# Difficulty in computing a constant $c$ from the convergence in probability problem and a doubt regarding uniform and beta distribution interrelation.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I want to compute a constant $\large c$ from a convergence of probability problem.

Also I have a doubt regarding the relation between the uniform and beta distribution.

The problem says -

> Suppose that $\large \{\mathrm{U_{n}}\}_{n \geq 1}$ is a sequence of iid random variables with uniform distribution over $\large (0,1)$. Define, $\large \mathrm{Y_{n}}= \large 
>  \frac{1}{n} \underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}}\frac{\mathrm{U_{i}^{4} (1-U_{i})^{4}}}{1+\mathrm{U_{i}^{2}}}$.
> $$\ $$ a. Compute the constant $\large c$ with justification where $\large \mathrm{Y_{n}} \overset{p}{\longrightarrow} c$ as $\large n \to \infty$. $$\ $$ b. Does the value of $\large c$ imply that $\large \pi <\frac{22}{7}$?

For part a here is my approach :-

> $\large \mathrm{Y_{n}} \overset{p}{\longrightarrow} c \implies \large \mathrm{Y_{n}} \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} c.$ $$\ $$ Also for any $\large \epsilon >0 $, $\large \underset{n\to \infty}{\lim} \mathbb{P} \Bigg [ \Huge\mid \large \mathrm{Y_{n}} - c\Huge \mid \large \geq \epsilon \Bigg ] \\ = \large 
> \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \Bigg[\large \mathbb{P} \Bigg (\mathrm{Y_{n}} \leq c - \epsilon \Bigg) + \mathbb{P} \Bigg (\mathrm{Y_{n}} \geq c + \epsilon \Bigg) \Bigg] \\ = \large 
> \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \large \mathbb{P} \Bigg (\mathrm{Y_{n}} \leq c - \epsilon \Bigg) + \large 
> \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \mathbb{P} \Bigg (\mathrm{Y_{n}} \geq c + \epsilon \Bigg)\\ = \large \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \mathrm{F_{Y_{n}}(c- \epsilon)} + \large 
> \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \mathbb{P} \Bigg (\mathrm{Y_{n}} \geq c + \epsilon \Bigg) \\= 0+ \large 
> \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \mathbb{P} \Bigg (\mathrm{Y_{n}} \geq c + \epsilon \Bigg) \qquad \because \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \mathrm{F_{Y_{n}}(c- \epsilon)}=0 \\  \geq \large 
> \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \mathbb{P} \Bigg (\mathrm{Y_{n}} \geq c + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \Bigg) \\ = \large 1 - \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \mathrm{F_{Y_{n}}(c+ \frac{\epsilon}{2})} = 0 \qquad \because \large \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \mathrm{F_{Y_{n}}(c+ \frac{\epsilon}{2})}=1 \\ \large \Longrightarrow \underset{n\to \infty}{\lim} \mathbb{P} \Bigg [ \Huge\mid \large \mathrm{Y_{n}} - c\Huge \mid \large \leq \epsilon \Bigg ] = 1 $. $$$$ Let's consider $\large \mathrm{Z_{i}} = \large \frac{\mathrm{U_{i}^{4} (1-U_{i})^{4}}}{1+\mathrm{U_{i}^{2}}}$ $$$$ Then  $\large \mathrm{Y_{n}}= \large \mathbb{E}(\mathrm{Z})$ $$$$ Now since we have $ \large \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \mathrm{F_{Y_{n}}(c+ \frac{\epsilon}{2})}=1 \\ \implies \large \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \mathbb{P}\Bigg [\mathrm{Y_{n}} \leq c+ \frac{\epsilon}{2} \Bigg]=1 \\ \implies \large \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \underset{0}{\overset{c+\frac{\epsilon}{2}}{\int}} \mathrm{Y_{n}} \ d(\mathrm{Y_{n}})= 1 \\ \implies \large \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \underset{0}{\overset{c+\frac{\epsilon}{2}}{\int}} \mathbb{E}(\mathrm{Z}) \ d \mathrm{Z}=1 \\ \implies \large 
> \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \underset{0}{\overset{c+\frac{\epsilon}{2}}{\int}}  \frac{1}{n} \underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}}\frac{\mathrm{U_{i}^{4} (1-U_{i})^{4}}}{1+\mathrm{U_{i}^{2}}} \ d \mathrm{U_{i}} =1 \\ \implies \large \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \frac{1}{n} \underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}} \underset{0}{\overset{c+\frac{\epsilon}{2}}{\int}} \frac{\mathrm{U_{i}^{4} (1-U_{i})^{4}}}{1+\mathrm{U_{i}^{2}}} \ d \mathrm{U_{i}} =1 \qquad \to (\star)  \text{[, can we apply Fubini here?]} $

---

And here I am stuck. I am only interested in the part a and I don't know whether I am going towards the right direction.

$•$ My questions are

1. How do we solve the integral $(\star)$ ? I am getting a longer form of the integral as follows

$\large \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \frac{1}{n} \underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}} \Bigg [\underset{0}{\overset{c+\frac{\epsilon}{2}}{\int}} \mathrm{U_{i}^{2}(1+\mathrm{U_{i}^{2}})} \ d \mathrm{U_{i}}+ \underset{0}{\overset{c+\frac{\epsilon}{2}}{\int}} 4 \frac{\mathrm{U_{i}^{6}}}{1+\mathrm{U_{i}^{2}}} \ d \mathrm{U_{i}} + \underset{0}{\overset{c+\frac{\epsilon}{2}}{\int}} \mathrm{U_{i}^{5}} \ d \mathrm{U_{i}} \Bigg ]=1$,

which I am cannot be sure whether it is correct.

2. If this is not the correct approach please kindly let me know and learn how to compute $\large c$ here.

$•$ if $U \sim U(0,1)$, then can we say that $U^k, (1-U)^k, [U(1-U)]^k$ and $1+U^k$ each of them individually follow a beta distribution? If they do then $Y_n$ in the problem will follow the additive property of gamma distribution .. but yet not sure how to compute $\large c$.

Therefore any help is valuable and highly appreciated. Please kindly help me.

Comment: What you should first notice is that $\frac{U_{i}^{4}(1-U_{i})^{4}}{1+U_{i}^{2}}$ are iid. And hence by the Strong/Weak Law, your $c$ will have to be $E( \frac{U_{1}^{4}(1-U_{1})^{4}}{1+U_{1}^{2}})=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-x)^{4}x^{4}}{1+x^{2}}dx$.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron, I have one question

I cannot understand why c is same as the expectation value.

Comment: Why don't you try and read up the law of large numbers that I mentioned.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron, thanks for the comment. I get it now. thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, we want to use the [weak law of large numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers). For this purpose let
$$X_i=\frac{U_i^4(1-U_i)^4}{1+U_i^2}.$$
Since the $U_i$ are i.i.d., so are the $X_i$. Let $\mu=\mathbb E[X_i]$ be the expected value (it doesn't matter what $i$ is as the $X_i$ are i.i.d.). The antiderivative of $f(u)=\frac{u^4(1-u)^4}{1+u^2}$ is
$$F(u)=\frac17u^7-\frac23u^6+u^5-\frac43u^3+4u-4\arctan(u),$$ which I obtained with an integral calculator from the internet. Since $U$ is uniform over $[0,1]$ we have $\mu=\int_0^1f(u)\mathrm du=F(1)-F(0)=\frac{22}7-\pi$.
Since $\mu$ is finite and the $X_i$ are i i.d., we can apply the weak law of large numbers to obtain that $Y_n=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ converges in probability to $c=\mu$.

Clearly we have $f(u)>0$ for $0<u<1$ and $f$ is continuous, which easily yields that $\mu>0$, so yes, this yields that $\pi<\frac{22}7$.
The weaker inequality $\pi\le\frac{22}7$ is also obvious from $Y_n\ge 0$, however the strict inequality cannot be obtained from the convergence in probability alone.
(However, if you may use that $\pi$ is irrational, that'd already be enough to get the strict inequality.)

If this is not detailed enough, I'm happy to add more details.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! This was a mistake on my side (I briefly forgot the scaling with $1/n$). I added some detail, hope it helps!

Comment: +1 for your answer. It is clear now. Thank you very much.